# Users cannot write to folders owned by the group they're a part of

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a shared folder with the following permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 52 Administrator Domain Users 4096 jun 29 16:00 prod
```

Everyone from the Domain Users group is able to write inside, but the other users cannot write inside the created folders. Permissions on the created folders are as follow (examples):

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 2  User2 Domain Users 4096 jun 23 17:00 _Software

drwxrwxr-x+ 47 Prod2 Domain Users 4096 jun 26 13:09 Gepack
```

So basically i can't seem to be able to allow users to write in folders created by other users inside this parent directory PROD.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm not too familiar with Linux.

## Edit 1

```
# file: prod/_Software
# owner: User2
# group: Domain\040Users
user::rwx
user:User2:rwx
group::r-x
group:Domain\040Users:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:User2:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:Domain\040Users:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: Add the output of `getfacl prod/_Software` to your question.

Comment: Added has requested, and thank you for your time.
So for what I'm looking is the group missing W permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ls -l` output is quite confusing when ACLs are involved in a certain way. The group `rwx` does not refer to the group any more (or not in certain situations). I am not sure about the rules.

In your case it shows `rwx` for the group because there is a named user (`User2`) with these permissions. The primary group only has `r-x`.

You have to manually fix this for all existing directories:

```
setfacl -m g::rwx _Software Gepack # ...
```

## default ACLs

In order to avoid this problem with future subdirectories you have to set a default ACL for the parent folder. You can either enforce the primary group for future child elements (`chmod g+s prod`) and set the default permissions for the primary group

```
setfacl -m d:g::rwx prod
```

or set permissions for a certain group

```
setfacl -m d:g:'Domain Users':rwx prod
```

Comment: So I'll have to do this setfacl -m g::rwx _Software Gepack # ... for every single folder inside the root directory PROD?

Comment: I used setfacl -m d:g::rwx prod command on the root directory, and was able to create a folder with 1 user and a file inside the folder with another..

Also after using  setfacl -m g::rwx on all the existing folder, I was able to copy and create new files normally with multiple users.. Tyvm

Comment: @user702897 Only for those directories which you want to be writable by the group members. You can shorten it to `setfacl -m g::rwx */` for all directories.